# Taking pairs of numbers representing begin/end, and removing overlaps

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11

I have an array of pairs that represent a range of [begin,end).  The array can be assumed to already sorted by the 'begin' field.

I want to generate a new array with all of the overlaps removed, and additional pairs created, as needed.

For example, let's say the array contained the following pairs:

```
[1,3],[2,5],[7,15],[8,9],[12,19]
```

The output should be as follows:

```
[1,2],[2,3],[3,5],[7,8],[8,9],[9,12],[12,15],[15,19]
```

Ultimately, the output array should contain no overlaps at all.

What's the most optimal solution that takes no more than O(m), where m is the number of entries needed in the output array?  I think I see a way to do it in O(n^2), where n is the number of entries in the input array, but there's got to be a better way.

The final implementation will be in C++11, using vectors of pairs of doubles, although pseudocode solutions are fine.

EDIT:

I appreciate all responses, but I would politely request in advance to please not post any solutions that depend on particular frameworks or libraries unless such frameworks are part of standard c++11.

Comment: I'm generating a new output array from scratch, so there's no deletion, and inserting into it can be assumed to be O(1).  Deletion can be assumed to be O(n) by itself.

Comment: seems like a Greedy Problem, check [Interval Scheduling](https://ocw.tudelft.nl/wp-content/uploads/Algoritmiek_Interval_scheduling.pdf)

Comment: Well, not exactly... inserting at the *END* of the output vector is O(1).  Inserting anywhere else is O(n).   I'm not sure the algorithm there would be any better than O(n^2).

Comment: In your output, I think it is missing [5.7].

Comment: No.  [5,7] is not inside of any range on the input.

Comment: I think O(n * log n) is the best you will get.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something, because it seems like there's a simple single-pass answer with O(1) extra storage.

Comment: I know the feeling, but I haven't been able to see it.     Also, an O(n log n) solution would be fine, but I can't see a way to do that either.

Comment: @aschepler: Really? What if all intervals are nested?

Comment: @Deduplicator Yup, that would be the missing thought.

Comment: "but I can't see a way to do that either." - so what is the need? a pseudocode?

Comment: Try to stuff all the numbers from the `vector<pair>` into a `std::set<int>` and take each successive pair of numbers from the set.   That's the first thought I have, but could have flaws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I'll solve a related problem; generate merged intervals that cover the same area with no adjacency or overlap.

Walk the input array.  Start with the first element.  Record highwater (end of interval) and lowater (start of interval).

Proceed forward.  Each element, if it overlaps the interval, extend highwater.  If not, output highwater and lowater as an interval, then record a new high and lowater.

This takes O(n) time on input.

Every element of input must be read, because any of them could go from their start location to the end and change the result.  So this is O-optimal.

---

This merges intervals into the largest contiguous one you can make; you want to save all of the "edges" or "seams" in the original intervals.  To solve your spec, simply keep track of seams (in order) and break the generated intervals at those seams.  "Lowater" seams will always come with increasing values; highwater seams may not.  So an ordered set of seams should work.  This is O(nlgn) sadly due to the set.

---

```
// half open
struct interval {
    int lowater = 0;
    int highwater = 0;
    bool empty() const {
        return lowater == highwater;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, interval i ) {
        return os << "[" << i.lowater << "," << i.highwater << "]";
    }
};


template<class Range, class Out>
void build_intervals( Range&& in, Out out ) {
    std::optional<interval> current;
    std::set<int> seams;

    auto dump_interval = [&](interval i){
        if (i.empty()) return;
        *out = i;
    };
    auto dump_current = [&]{
        if (!current) return;

    //    std::cout << "Dumping " << *current << " with seams: {";
        for (int seam:seams) {
    //        std::cout << seam << ",";
            dump_interval({ current->lowater, seam });
            current->lowater = seam;
        }
    //    std::cout << "}\n";
        dump_interval( *current );
        current = std::nullopt;
        seams.clear();
    };
    for (auto&& e : in) {
        if (current && e.lowater <= current->highwater) {
            seams.insert(e.lowater);
            seams.insert(e.highwater);
    //        std::cout << "No gap between " << *current << " and " << e << "\n";
            current->highwater = (std::max)(e.highwater, current->highwater);
    //        std::cout << "Combined: " << *current << "\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (!current) {
    //        std::cout << "New current " << e << "\n";
        } else {
    //        std::cout << "Gap between " << *current << "  and " << e << "\n";
            dump_current();
        }
        current = e;
        seams.insert(e.lowater);
        seams.insert(e.highwater);
    }
    dump_current();
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c06a5301dcd2f08).

Comment: Did you try test-case [1,6] [2,5] [3,4] or alike?

Comment: @dedup aha, I was solving the wrong problem.  Fixed.

Comment: Interesting use as a building-block.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something like this, by adding just couple of if it is done in O(n) time. I'm just not sure about last elements, my output:

```
[1 : 2], [2 : 3], [3 : 5], [7 : 8], [8 : 9], [9 : 12], [12 : 15], [15 : 19]
```

Maybe its something that would help:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> noOverlaps(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& input) {
    if (input.size() <= 1) {
        return input;
    }
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> result;
    result.push_back(input[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        //If overlap
        if (input[i].first < result.back().second) {
            auto lastOne = result.back();
            result.pop_back();
            result.push_back(std::make_pair(lastOne.first, input[i].first));
            if (lastOne.second > input[i].second) {
                result.push_back(std::make_pair(input[i].first, input[i].second));
                result.push_back(std::make_pair(input[i].second, lastOne.second));
            } else {
                result.push_back(std::make_pair(input[i].first, lastOne.second));
                result.push_back(std::make_pair(lastOne.second, input[i].second));
            }
        } else {
            result.push_back(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Update 1**
As pointed out in the comment above will not work with multiple overlapping intervals, so the above solution can be improved by swallowing intervals that are containing each other and run the same algorithm:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> noOverlaps(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& origInput) {
    if (origInput.size() <= 1) {
        return origInput;
    }
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> result;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> input;
    input.push_back(origInput[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < origInput.size(); ++i) {
        if (input[i-1].first <= origInput[i].first && input[i-1].second >= origInput[i].second) {
            continue;
        }
        input.push_back(origInput[i]);
    }

    result.push_back(input[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        //If overlap
        if (input[i].first < result.back().second) {
            auto lastOne = result.back();
            result.pop_back();
            result.push_back(std::make_pair(lastOne.first, input[i].first));
            if (lastOne.second > input[i].second) {
                result.push_back(std::make_pair(input[i].first, input[i].second));
                result.push_back(std::make_pair(input[i].second, lastOne.second));
            } else {
                result.push_back(std::make_pair(input[i].first, lastOne.second));
                result.push_back(std::make_pair(lastOne.second, input[i].second));
            }
        } else {
            result.push_back(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But this requires 2xO(n) space complexity and code is not nice.

So I just wonder would that not be enough:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> noOverlaps2(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& origInput) {
    if (origInput.size() <= 1) {
        return origInput;
    }
    int low = origInput[0].first, high = origInput[0].second;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> result;

    for (int i = 1; i < origInput.size(); ++i) {
        if (high < origInput[i].first) {
            result.emplace_back(low, high);
            low = origInput[i].first;
            high = origInput[i].second;
        } else {
            high = std::max(origInput[i].second, high);
        }
    }
    result.emplace_back(low, high);

    return result;
}
```

For your data it gives output:`[1 : 5], [7 : 19]` but it get rid of overlaps.

Comment: What about multi-overlap?

Comment: Can you give input example?

Comment: Input `[[1,6],[2,5],[3,4]]` gives output `[[1,2],[2,5],[5,3],[3,4],[4,6]]`.

Comment: I see, what about in first iteration merging those elements that contains each other and are next to each other and then applying the solution?